# 'tuple' object is not callable (python)

Tags: python

so this is my first game im working on (snake) and it gave me an error: `ln 21, in update
self.rect.centerx += self.direction(0) *2, 'tuple' object is not callable.`
and i've looked it up for answers but i didnt seem to find my problem and i dont know what 'tuple' means, the full game-code is here:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


class SnakeHead(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load('data/snake_head.png') 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = 320
        self.rect.centery = 240    

        self.direction = (0,-1) 
        self.crashed = False


    def render(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.centerx += self.direction(0) * 2
        self.rect.centery += self.direction(1) * 2

        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
            self.crashed = True

        if self.rect.right > 639:
                self.rect.right = 639
                self.crashed = True

        if self.rect.top < 0:
                self.rect.top = 0
                self.crashed = True

        if self.rect.bottom > 479:
                self.rect.bottom = 479
                self.crashed = True 

def run_game():
    pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480)) 

snakehead = SnakeHead()

clock = pygame.time.Clock() 




while 1:

    clock.tick(32)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            return 


    screen.fill((175,175,175))

    snakehead.update() 
    snakehead.render(screen) 

    pygame.display.flip() `
```

i've been asking myself what the probelem was for over 2 hours, but couldnt find anything and would be super happy if someone could tell me :)

-Xattics

Comment: "i dont know what 'tuple' means" - Then look it up?

Comment: i did... but it didnt really give an explanation to it. and im quite new to it, so dont be so harsh to me please...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line is the problem

```
self.rect.centerx += self.direction(0) * 2
```

`direction` is a `tuple`, if you meant to index you should do

```
self.rect.centerx += self.direction[0] * 2
```

Comment: thanks, and why does these kinds of points get so many downvotes? is there something wrong with what i asked?